# Image disappears in Figure* environment when using [H]

Tags: floats, two-column

I am using a standard [twocolumn]{article} class, but want to insert a image that spans both columns. To do this I am using the figure* environment, but when I use the [H] option, my image disappears.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{float}

%% Packages I've tried to use for work arounds
%%\usepackage{dblfloatfix}  % position images that span both columns
%%\usepackage{subcaption}
%%\usepackage{placeins}
%%\usepackage{afterpage}


\begin{document}

\title{Example Article}


%% main text
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\newpage
\section{Results}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{images/file_name}
    \caption{caption}~\label{fig:figure1}
\end{figure*}

\clearpage

\section{Conclusions}
\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

The intro and results paragraphs are both short, so I want them at the top, with the image at the bottom spanning both columns. Any suggestions?

Comment: So your underlying question is: "You have a figure you want to place at the top of the first page that spans both columns in a `twocolumn` article." Correct? Does your `Introduction` section span *only* the first column, while your `Results` section span *only* the second column?

Comment: @Werner, the intent is actually to have the image at the bottom, with a one paragraph intro at the top in the left column, and a one paragraph results paragraph at the top in the right column.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, they don't generate a warning for me, but for the purpose of this question, you can delete them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Edited.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two column `figure*` is only compatible with `[tp]`. There is a fix in `dblfloatfix.sty` to use `[b]` but that will put the figure on the bottom of next page. Still not compatible with `[h]`. The easiest way I can think of, if the columns look something in the example, is to place it yourself using a `minipage`. I have used `\captionof` from the `caption` package to get the caption.

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}%% To get \captionof

%% Packages I've tried to use for work arounds
%%\usepackage{dblfloatfix}  % position images that span both columns
%%\usepackage{subcaption}
%%\usepackage{placeins}
%%\usepackage{afterpage}

\begin{document}

\title{Example Article}
\maketitle

%% main text
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
See Figure~\ref{fig:figure1}.

\vfill
\noindent
\begin{minipage}{1.0\textwidth}
  \strut\newline
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{caption}\label{fig:figure1}
\end{minipage}

\newpage
\section{Results}
\lipsum[1]

% \begin{figure*}[tb]
%     \centering
%     \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth,height=5cm]{example-image}
%     \caption{caption}\label{fig:figure1}
% \end{figure*}

\clearpage
\section{Conclusions}
\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This displays what I'm looking for! I had considered minipage, but was wondering if there were alternative ways to do this.

Comment: This does work pretty well though. I would just note that I used `\vfill` before the `\noindent` starting the `minipage` block to force the image to the bottom.

Comment: @gghh3456, That seems reasonable. I have updated accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

You can try  `stfloats` which will place the figure on the current page *if it is defined in the first column*.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}% 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\begin{document}
 \section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}[b]
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-image}
  \caption{This is a example.}
\end{figure*}
\newpage
\section{Results}
\lipsum[1]


\lipsum[3-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: The example above contains no \maketitle, so I ignored it. But if I add it to my example it works fine.

Comment: Interesting. This certainly displays the page how I want, but I think a solution where I can keep the figure code in the correct place in the text code would be preferable.

Comment: Well you will have to. LaTeX can't know that you want a short first column if the picture isn't there. The "minipage" solution from Stefan  needs this too (and before you consider the "minipage" solution: make the result text a bit longer, e.g. with \lipsum[1-2] and check what happens.)

Answer (score 8):

To place a figure or table spanning both columns as with the `[H]` option, you can use the `cuted` package also from the `sttools` bundle, and the `\captionof` command:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx, caption}
\usepackage{cuted}

\begin{document}

 \section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{strip}
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Gauguin.png}

  \captionof{figure}{D'où venons-nous ? Que sommes-nous ? Où allons-nous ?.}
\end{strip}
\newpage
\section{Results}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[3-10]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is close, but it gives me problems in terms of text formatting. If I get rid of the `\newpage` command before my results section, then two problems arise: 1) The Results section isn't in a new column which is what I want 2) There's text below the image from the next section that I can't get rid of with `\newpage` / `\clearapage`. ![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/2E5G5OU.png) However, if I do include `\newpage`, instead of starting it in the right column, it deletes the hangover from the previous section and starts it new in the left column. ![Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/vlu4HPp.png)

Comment: This worked well for me for the ACM two-column conference template.