# How to fix PDF figure between text in LaTex (My PDF figure alsways embed on last page {after the references})

Tags: floats, positioning

I am using double column format and want to put my PDF figure on whole page. I want to put my PDF figure in between text, **but my picture is displaying on last page of file when i generated the latex PDF**. and using following command which is given below. 
How i can fix my PDF picture position???

```
\begin{figure*}[!ht]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Figure6.pdf}
    \caption{Taxonomy of SDN based smart building.}
    \label{fig:mesh1}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Why are you putting your picture inside a floating (`figure`) environment, if you don't want it to float? Also: please make a compilable example → What is a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: the only reason to use a `figure` environment is to allow latex to move  it, and as you have used the optional argument to specify that it may not be placed on a page of figures, it is quite likely to go to the end of the document. add `p` to the option or perhaps just remove the option altogether.

Comment: The question is unclear by the lack of a MWE but it is not answered in the question linked as duplicate.  Of the nine answers there, none cover the special case of the`figure*` float in a two column document. However I am sure that there are answers covering this specific case elsewhere ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  "I am using a double column format"  maybe mean 1-col with multicol, but assuming a true 2-col, just because `[h]` is superfluous in this type of float, have no sense link now this question to answers that are all about fixing position using  [!h] (already tried by the OP without success) or worse, `[H]`  (that in this case,  can remove the float instead of fix the positions).  Of course, add another answer there resolve the contradiction, ...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ... but what about the  answers of   https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368080/image-disappears-in-figure-environment-when-using-h or even the comments of ttps://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/303212/force-figure-placement-in-twocolumn-elsarticle

Comment: @Fran sorry when coming back to this question after your ping I missed the OPs comment about 2-col I will delete the comment above to avoid confusion, but as I say I think it's Ok to be a dup, unless you want to add a 2-col answer here rather than there, in which case I'll vote to re-open (which will re-open)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Leave it closed. I did not intend to answer, but  as unwarily I have involved myself, so finally I left an attempt of answer in the other question.