# Wide figure or two column figure

Tags: floats

How to place two column figure in any position of a page.
Two column figure can be placed only top or bottom?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! See if the package `cuted` and its environment `strip` can help you. As example of its use, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368080

Comment: One approach is to use multicol.  While multicol does not support floats, odds are you don't want your figures to float anyway.  So you end and begin multicol whenever you add a figure (in onecolumn).  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329709/how-to-put-figure-at-middle-or-at-desired-position-on-a-page/531802?r=SearchResults&s=1|35.3145#531802