# How could i insert a table or photo in documentclass[twocolumn]?

Tags: minipage, two-column, multicolumn, double-sided

I Need to insert a photo in documentclass[twocolumn], but without use blindtext or lipsum, and  I need the photo be in the middle of page. and text above the photo does complete tow columns.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{multicol}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multicols

\begin{document}
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello 
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello 

\begin{figure*}[bt]
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-image}
  \caption{example-image.}
\end{figure*}
hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please show a sketch of the desired output. Where exactly should the image be placed?

Comment: Horizontal centered at bottom  or top of page or somewhere around middle of the page? In the latter case see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368080/

Comment: sorry   @leandriis  I was meaning  table or photo.

Comment: What's the problem with the `lipsum` or the `blindext` packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't recommend placing a wide image in the middle of a page as is makes is unclear for the reader where the text continues after the upper half of the left column. Do you continue reading in ht elower half of the left column or in the upper half of the right column? In the following MWE that is done using the `strip` environment from the `cuted` package and `captionof` from the `caption` package, the latter is the case:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{cuted}
\usepackage{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\section{Introducation}

hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello 
hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello hello 

\begin{strip}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}{example-image.}
\end{strip}


hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi hi  

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can ! (But my apology for the typo, it was `multicols` (and not multicol)!)

Here is a working MWE compiled with PdfLatex:

```
\documentclass[twocolumns]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
[
\section{First Section}
All human things are subject to decay, and when fate summons, Monarchs must obey.
] % You can add some text that spans two columns using []
Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what a printed text will look like at this place.
If you read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there...
\end{multicols}

\vspace{3pt} %This is optional

\begin{figure*}[h]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=5cm]{img1012}
    \caption{example-image.}
\end{figure*}
\vspace{3pt} 
\begin{multicols}{2}
Hello, here is some text without a meaning.  This text should show what a printed text will look like at this place.
If you read this text, you will get no information.  Really?  Is there no information?  Is there...
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This somehow looks like an addendum to your previous answer/a reply to the comment on your previour answer. Probably it yould be better to just edit/update said previour answer instead of adding a new, second one here.

Comment: Regarding the contents of your answer: You claim that one can use `multicols` from the `multicol` package inside of a `twocolumn` `article` document and indeed show a result in which it apears to work. This is because the class option is called `twocolumn` instead of the `twocolumns` you used. This typo can easily be spotted when inspecting the warning you get when compiling your code. "Warning: Unused global option(s):". [...]

Comment: [...] If one removes the extra "s"  from the option, one gets an entirely different output and yet another warning informing us about `multicol` not working inside of a `twocolumn` document class: "Package multicol Warning: May not work with the twocolumn option"

Answer (score 0):

Not being an expert, I'll only share how I found a solution when I had the similar issue.
With the package `multicol`, you have the environment `multicol` that will indicate when the columns begin and end.

```
\begin{multicol}
\lipsum
\end[multicol}
```

followed by your image

```
\begin{figure*}[bt]
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=4cm]{example-image}
  \caption{example-image.}
\end{figure*}
```

Then use the environment `multicol` again

```
\begin{multicol}
\lipsum
\end[multicol}
```

That should be working.

Comment: thanks to answer, but you can't use multicol environment with documentclass[twocolumn].